# vim: Unable to copy & paste in Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, vim

After upgrading to Debian Stretch, we have been unable to copy&paste with the mouse in MacOS Sierra and Windows clients alike.

I have tried several solutions, including from this thread, without much sucess. [Copy-paste for vim is not working when mouse (:set mouse=a) is on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139578/copy-paste-for-vim-is-not-working-when-mouse-set-mouse-a-is-on)

I have tried to place in `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` the followings lines:

```
set vb t_vb=
set mouse=""
```

and besides `mouse=""`, `mouse="a"` `mouse="r"` and `mouse="v"`, and none of the solutions worked.

What do seems to work, it to comment in the file `/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim` the following lines:

```
"if has('mouse')
"  set mouse=a
"endif
```

As soon those lines are commented out, we are able to copy&paste again.

However, those changes are lost in the next `vim` upgrade.

Any suggestions for a more permanent solution?

Comment: Recent versions of Vim added bracketed pasting in `xterm`s.  The initial implementation was less than perfect, and a number of bugs were fixed in subsequent patches.  So if you're running a recent version but not the latest, you may be affected by said bugs.  FWIW.

Comment: @SatoKatsura It is not bracketed pasting...it does not copy anything at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you conclude it isn't related to bracketed pasting?

Comment: @SatoKatsura It completely ignores the copy operation. The paste returns the previous copy before the intended.

Comment: Yup, this sounds quite similar to a problem reported to `vim_dev`.  It turned out it was related to bracketed pasting.  It certainly isn't normal behavior, so feel free to post a bug report if you think it's something else.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Interesting. Will try to find more about it.

Comment: [You can find the right solution or a keyboard trick explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381625/197391)

Comment: @snariom38 At work I am having that bug using Mac and Windows, no xterm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

```
set mouse=r
```

I did edit the default file because there were more defaults changed since jessie.

```
vi /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim
```

because somehow now syntax highlighting was on at default and all the users complained.

Comment: Do not edit `defaults.vim` as that file will be squashed in each upgrade. However I do confirm that `set mouse=r` now is working. As per my question, it was not working in the beta I tried.

Answer (score 5):

Do:

```
sudo touch /etc/vim/vimrc.local
```

Then edit the file:

```
" This file loads the default vim options at the beginning and prevents
" that they are being loaded again later. All other options that will be set,
" are added, or overwrite the default settings. Add as many options as you
" whish at the end of this file.

" Load the defaults
source /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim

" Prevent the defaults from being loaded again later, if the user doesn't
" have a local vimrc (~/.vimrc)
let skip_defaults_vim = 1


" Set more options (overwrites settings from /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim)
" Add as many options as you whish

" Set the mouse mode to 'r'
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=r
endif
```

This will apply the rule for the whole system and all users.
Tested on Debian 9.3.

Answer (score 2):

I did it, setting this option in my local vimrc file

`echo "set mouse-=a" > ~/.vimrc`

Comment: Unfortunately, it also does not work.

Comment: have various debian instances and one where only this works [shrug]